# Nowhere dense sets and metric space

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, metric-spaces, solution-verification, axiom-of-choice

Excuse me can you see this question
Prove that in a metric space the frontier of an open set is the set of accumulation points of a discrete set ... 
It wrote that " this requires the axioms of choice and is difficult "

Comment: That is false..

Comment: It os a question from Stephen Willard , general topology book

Comment: @WilliamElliot: On the contrary, it is true: see [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3270476/in-a-metric-space-x-the-boundary-of-an-open-set-is-the-set-of-all-limit-point) (though at the moment the link in Henno’s answer is not accessible).

Comment: How can i get the link ,?

Comment: @Aya: I don’t know; it may just be down temporarily.

Comment: When asking questions, please  include your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve left some details to be checked, but here’s an approach that appears to work.

Let $\langle X,d\rangle$ be a metric space, let $U$ be a non-empty open set in $X$, and let $F=\operatorname{bdry}U$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $V_n=U\cap\bigcup_{x\in F}B(x,2^{-n})$ and $R_n=V_n\setminus V_{n+1}$. For $\epsilon>0$ say that a set $D\subseteq X$ is $\epsilon$-discrete if $d(x,y)\ge\epsilon$ whenever $x,y\in D$ and $x\ne y$.

> **Proposition.** Let $A\subseteq X$ and $\epsilon>0$. Then there is an maximal $\epsilon$-discrete $D\subseteq A$, i.e., one such that $A\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in D}B(x,\epsilon)$.
>
> **Proof.** Construct $D$ by (possibly transfinite) recursion. Choose $x_0\in A$ arbitrarily. Given an ordinal $\eta$ and points $x_\xi\in A$ for all $\xi<\eta$, let $D=\{x_\xi:\xi<\eta\}$ if $\bigcup_{\xi<\eta}B(x_\xi,\epsilon)\supseteqq A$, and otherwise choose $x_\eta\in A\setminus\bigcup_{\xi<\eta}B(x_\xi,\epsilon)$ and continue. This must stop at some point. (Alternatively, this could be accomplished with Zorn’s lemma.) $\dashv$

For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $D_n$ be a maximal $2^{-(2n+2)}$-discrete subset of $R_{2n}$, and let $D=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}D_n$. Then $D$ is discrete, and $F$ is the set of accumulation points of $D$.

Comment: Brian, if you dont mind, are there any research level journals for beginners that you recommend? how can the novice get into math research?

Comment: @ILoveMath: I don’t mind, but I don’t think that I can answer that. I’m definitely out of touch with journals: it’s been quite a few years since I was actively keeping up even with my own field. As for getting started, I’d say that the first step is finding one or two areas that especially interest you and trying to read some papers to get an idea of what people are doing. One good place to browse for them is [arxiv.org](https://arxiv.org/archive/math).